# Using a <select multiple> to filter divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have  like:

```
<div class="numbers one two three">...</div>
<div class="numbers one three five">...</div>
<div class="numbers two four six">...</div>
<div class="numbers one two four">...</div>
```

and I have a select like:

```
<select id="filternumbers" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
    <option value="five">Five</option>
    <option value="six">Six</option>
</select>
```

How do I get the select to filter divs based on my selection, say "two" and "four" - meaning only last two divs should be visible?

I know I can do this for single select menus:

```
$('#filternumbers').on('change', function () {
    var number = $(this).val();
    $(".numbers").hide();
    $(".numbers").hasClass(number).show();
});
```

But how do I do it for a multi select?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [`$.fn.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) divs by combination of class names:

```js
$('#filternumbers').on('change', function () {
    var number = $(this).val();
    var classNames = '.' + number.join('.');
    $(".numbers").hide().filter(classNames).show();
});
```

```css
.numbers {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="filternumbers" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
    <option value="five">Five</option>
    <option value="six">Six</option>
</select>

<div class="numbers one two three">one two three</div>
<div class="numbers one three five">one three five</div>
<div class="numbers two four six">two four six</div>
<div class="numbers one two four">one two four</div>
```

Comment: he is using multi select, so i think he wants to handle when multiple options are selected

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadkari jQuery handles multiselection transparently, and `val()` returns an array of selections in this case. Just try it out with my demo.

Comment: I don't want them hidden on page load. They **all** should be visible on page load. But the filter should apply when a user decides to "filter" the results

Comment: yes it works, upvoted for less code, thanks for increasing my knowledge :)

Comment: @D-Day : just remove `.numbers {display: none;}`

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadkari facepalming myself. Didn't even see that.

Answer (score 1):

You can check all the values which are checked first and run each() for checked values and then show the requied values using filter

```
$('#filternumbers').on('change', function () {
    $(".numbers").hide();
    $('#filternumbers option:selected').each(function() {
        var number = $(this).val();
        var classNames = '.' + number;
        $(".numbers").filter(classNames).show();
    });

});
```

refer jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gsmd2jd3/